# Access previous row in dataframe, indexed on date with gaps

Tags: r

I have a `dataframe` indexed on the dates, with 4 columns `'Open',High,'Low','Close'`.

The dates in index are all the trading dates, thus it does not include holidays and weekends.

I can get the value of the row for 27 Dec 2015 in the dataframe by using

```
dataframe["2015-12-27",]
```

I need to get the value of the previous and next rows. Since the previous row does not necessarily have to be "2015-12-26" as that date can be a holiday or a weekend, a simple arithmetic subtraction wont work.

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**  I wonder why the negative votes. I think the answer would definitely benefit someone else in future. But then there may be some sense in collective wisdom, that I cant grasp.

Comment: As a last resort, you could subtract until you get a valid (non-NA/NULL) answer, catching results in a `tryCatch`.

Comment: You can use match i.e. `i1 <- match("2015-12-17", index(dataframe)); dataframe[i1-1,]`

Comment: @RomanLuštrik or a cleaner solution.

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "access". But you could add 2 more columns that are lag and lead of your current time column. E.g. `c(NA, df$col[1:(length(df$col)-1)])`

Comment: @akrun i1 is coming as NA. index(dataframe) has the value "2015-12-27", but when I use i1 <- match("2015-12-17", index(dataframe)); its null.

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example with `dput`

Comment: @akun Small change and got it working. Needed to add as.Date . i1 <- match(as.Date("2015-12-17"), index(dataframe));  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, as mentioned in the comments, is:

```
var1 <- match(as.Date("2015-12-26"), index(dataframe));
prevValue <- dataframe[var1-1,]
currentValue<- dataframe[var1,]
nextValue<- dataframe[var1+1,]
```

Cheers